# String.ToLower in C# DLL library

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am newbie in C#, so, please, sorry my silly question :).

I have two projects - C# exe and C# DLL.

In the C# exe code

```
private static byte[] toBytes(String str)
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII").GetBytes(
                str.ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

This works fine, but in C# DLL there is no

```
str.ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

method, only

```
str.ToLower();
```

What's wrong with my code/ DLL project? Why is

```
str.ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

not available in the C# DLL project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will very much depend on the kind of class library project you created. For example if you are targeting .NET Core or a portable class library, then only the `ToLower()` method is implemented and available.

According to the documentation the [`.ToLower(CultureInfo culture)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8z5yt00(v=vs.110).aspx) method is available in the Full .NET framework (>= 1.1), Silverlight (>= 2.0) and Windows Phone Silverlight (>= 7.0).

Answer (score 1):

In a PCL project, you should use the [string.ToLowerInvariant()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant.aspx) to achieve this purpose.